# How many to form a committee like this?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A committee of 5 to be chosen from 4 women and 8 men, if at least 2 men and 2 women are on the committee, how many different committees?
The answer given is there are either 3 men and 2 women or 3 women and 2 men. So, it's C(8,2) x C(4,3) + C(8,3) x C(4,2) which = 448.

That sounds reasonable, but I didn't think of that way, and instead my reasoning was there are 2 men and 2 women plus one other of either. So it's C(8,2) x C(4,2) x C(8,1) = 1344. And that last one is chosen from the remaining 8...

I'm trying to understand why my reasoning is wrong, and I'm not seeing it. It seems to me both answers should come to the same. Can anyone explain, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since either three women and two men are selected or two women and three men are selected the correct count is 
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{8}{2} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{3}$$

You are counting each committee three times.  For example, suppose the five people who have been selected to serve on the committee are Andrew, Bruce, Charlotte, Deborah, and Elizabeth.  Your method counts this committee three times, once for each way of designating one of the three women as the additional woman:

\begin{array}{l l l}
\text{two men} & \text{two women} & \text{additional woman}\\ \hline
\text{Andrew, Bruce} & \text{Charlotte, Deborah} & \text{Elizabeth}\\
\text{Andrew, Bruce} & \text{Charlotte, Elizabeth} & \text{Deborah}\\
\text{Andrew, Bruce} & \text{Deborah, Elizabeth} & \text{Charlotte}
\end{array}

Similarly, if you selected a committee with three men and two women, your method counts it three times, once for each way you could designate one of the three men as the additional man.

Notice that 
$$\color{red}{\binom{3}{1}}\binom{4}{3}\binom{8}{2} + \color{red}{\binom{3}{1}}\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{3} = \color{red}{\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{8}{1}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'd jump on the incorrect method on the first thought.  Is there a name to this pitfall (beside triple-countring)?  Is there a way to intuitively recognize it?

Comment: I don't quite see a pattern in your `notice` formula.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}{\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{8}{1}}$ at the end?

Comment: @J.Doe  Yes, I did.  Good catch.  The factors of $\binom{3}{1}$ on the LHS reflect the number of ways that you could designate one of the three women as the additional women if you choose three women or one of the three men as the additional men if you choose three men.  I used red to indicate that is where the error in your count arose.

Comment: How can I intuitively see that ${3\choose 1}$ in the first place?  I fell for the trap so easily.

Comment: The factor of $\binom{3}{1}$ is not what is important here.  What is important is that we consider cases depending on how many men and how many women are on the committee.   The set of men from which we are choosing is disjoint from the set of women from which we are choosing, so there is no danger of counting the same committee more than once.  However, when you chose a committee with three women and two men, the set of women from which the additional woman is chosen is not disjoint from the set of women from which which you chose the two designated women, which leads to over counting.

Comment: Ah.... so it is the joint/disjoint problem that I overlooked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are double counting.  When you choose the last person, you count it as different from choosing him or her first, even though you get the same committee.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  How do I correct the error?  That last 8 is from the remaining 6 men and 2 women.  Isn't exclusion already accounted for?

Comment: Got the answer from the other post.  It's actually triple counting.